# Add totals to last row of criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a simple macro to add totals from column B based on the spread number of column A. Using VBA I have the following code:

```
Sub SpacingTotals()
    Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, Temp As Range

    Set Rng = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set Temp = Rng(1)

    For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not Dn.Value = Temp Then
            Set Temp = Dn
        End If

        Dn.Offset(, 0) = Dn.Value
        Temp.Offset(, 2) = Temp.Offset(, 2) + Dn.Offset(, 1).Value
    Next Dn

End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is more of a formatting issue. I want the totals on the last line of the spread criteria rather than the first line (See image).

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

[image: Should be]

Comment: Note - this is probably doable with just a formula. Is VBA a must?

Comment: You could use a PivotTable for this.

Comment: Put in C2 and copy down: `=IF(A2<>A3,SUM($B$1:$B2)-SUM($C$1:$C1),"")`

Comment: to keep your vba going I would create a variable to store the running total and then when A does not match the previous A, paste the variable to the spreadsheet

Comment: @BigBen VBA isn't necessarily a must but I was trying not to bog the spreadsheet down with formulas. What I'm showing as an example is a simplified version of the spreadsheet which does have a ton of formulas. Which is why I decided to switch to VBA for this particular part.

Comment: You can write the formula, and then hard-code its value (with `.Value` = `.Value` on the range).

Comment: @Damian I would agree but since this is just an example of what I'm doing the actual spreadsheet is much more complex and uses a ton of formulas etc... In order to keep things together I can't really get away with a PivotTable. I appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: @BigBen oh good idea! that should do the trick!

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the formula! I think if I hardcode that using BigBen's suggestion that should get me where I need to be. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version using the variable `total` to be the running total. When the `spread` in the next row doesn't match the current row, the `total` is written in the column to the right.

```
Sub SpacingTotals()

    Dim total As Long

    Dim spread As Range
    For Each spread In Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)

        total = total + spread.offset(0, 1).Value2

        If spread.Value2 <> spread.offset(1, 0).Value2 Then
            spread.offset(0, 2).Value2 = total
            total = 0
        End If

    Next spread

End Sub
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! Appreciate your's and everyone else help too!